# displaying the most popular pages on my site

Tags: php, mysql, join

On my homepage I want to display the 30 most popular pages on my site. I thought the best way to do this would be to have a hit counter for each individual page, a column in the table called hit_counter. Then whenever a page is viewed the hit_counter is incremented by 1.

However my site has many different tables, e.g. hotels, restaurants, entertainment. I want them all to be mixed in the results, but I am not sure what the query would be to pull these all from the database.

I imagine it would be some sort of join. I would also want to take the name, description and url of each row, I have named the columns in a generic manor, e.g. hotel_name, hotel_description, hotel_url, restaurant_name, restaurant_description, etc.

Then the query would ORDER BY hit_counter DESC.

So what is the query to do such a join, my tables are called restaurants, hotels and entertainment.

Comment: What is the relationship between a page and the restaurants, hotels, and entertainment tables?

Comment: what do you mean relationship? They are all in the same database, in different tables. They have no relationship, I just want to consolidate them. I guess the only relationship would be the hit_counter.

Comment: Well I havent set it up yet, but I thought I would add a new column to each table called `hit_counter`. Alternatively, I would have a new table called `hit_counter`, but then it would be difficult to have a column to identify a page, due to the nature of different categories.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you are creating new table for each category page. In my opinion the best approach would be if you created 1 table for pages, 1 for categories and one for hits. You can also have hotels table, restaurant table, etc., but there's a difference between hotels table and pages table.....hotels should store info about each hotel and pages should store info about each page.

Anyways, category table would look like this:

```
ID
Category
```

Pages table should look like this:

```
ID
Category_id
url
title
description
etc
```

Hits table should look like this:

```
ID
category_id
page_id
hits
```

This way is much easier to write a query

```
'SELECT p.url, p.description, p.title, h.hits FROM pages p JOIN hits h ON p.id=h.page_id ORDER BY h.hits DESC LIMIT 30'
```

NOT TESTED BUT THIS IS THE IDEA HOW I WOULD DO IT.

PS: sorry if any typos

Comment: right, yes, that would be much easier if I created one table for all of them, but they have lots of other different fields. That was the only way I could think of doing it at this stage also. But I was wondering if there as some other way.

Comment: And I also wanted to include articles in there too.

Comment: To find other way for your question I would have to see your db structure and try it before I post code. As I said, I'm not sure if I understood your question right. However, I do strongly recommend to have a good DB structure so your work becomes easier in the future. Complex db structure for something simple can only lead to more problems and more bugs. I've learn that the hard way.